# Получить из базы клиентов у которых общая сумма всех заказов > 1000

Tags: mysql, sql, cms, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Дано:
Prestashop 1.7
База с префиксом ps_

Цель:
Получить из таблицы orders (тут поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если не там ищу) id всех клиентов, у которых общая сумма заказов превысила 1000.

Проблема:
В силу слабого опыта работы с SQL, не знаю как из orders погруппировать заказы по клиентам (id_customer) сложить в этих заказах все оплаты (total_paid) и показать те, у которых финальная сумма всех заказов, больше 1000.

Вот так, показываю всех клиентов кто за один раз, заказал больше чем на 1000, но цель не в этом.

SELECT `id_customer` FROM ps_orders WHERE `total_paid` > 1000

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попробовать:

```
SELECT id_customer, count(total_paid) 
FROM ps_orders
WHERE total_paid > 1000
GROUP BY id_customer
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос